# Simulate a slide-in page opening that starts at the top when scrolled

Tags: scroll, load, css-transitions

*I had a hard time wondering how to explain this with words, so I've made a quick wireframe sketch to explain the issue.*

[image: wireframe]

I'm creating a webapp that shows a long list of news items. When someone clicks a news item, by `.load()` I load a `.html` file into a `div` and with CSS-transitions I simulate the slide-in effect.

However, since that `div` is part of the page itself and the users scrolls on the page the loaded div with the news item itself gets  scrolled too.

Check out a live example of this issue [here](http://flagstonedesign.nl/app/). **Resize your browser!**

**Desired solution**
No matter how much you've scrolled on the overview page, when you click on an item and `.load()` and slide in that `div` with content, it should start at the top, instead of equally scrolled.

*The prototype will only be build for for an iPhone 6+, so only consider iOS in your solution if that matters.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With JavaScript

You could do this with JavaScript if so desired. I noticed your webpage uses jQuery, so this solution should just be able to work with what you have right now.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
```

This will animate scrolling to the top of the webpage. Change the '500' to something else for a slower effect.

## Without JavaScript

You can consider making the side section only fill 100% of the browser window, and have it's own scroll area instead. This should mean that the side only scrolls, and when the content is replaced it should scroll to the top automatically (assuming you remove the element and re-add it).

Comment: I've consider such solution, however that results in one minor, undesirable problem. Once the user clicks on the 'back' button to close the item he is stuck at the top, having to scroll down again to where he left. Any way to solve that? Edit: Can this be done by saving the current scroll top when a user clicks and scroll to that point when he clicks the back button?

Comment: I'm sure there's a way you can capture where the top of the user's screen is in relation to the webpage. I think ```$("html").offset().top``` should do the trick. Just set it to a variable before you scroll to the top.